# Change Background Color CSS with Timer JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, colors, jquery-animate

I was hoping someone could show me efficient JQuery to animate between 4 background colors in a div class.

I would like these events to be triggered by time, not click or hover.  I've seen posts on hover and toggle, but as someone not very proficient in JQuery, I didn't feel comfortable copying and pasting parts here and there.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I dont know if you mean animated as in fading to the next, but heres a simple quick example of changing the color every 2 seconds. First example does not require jQuery.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/7peJT/3/)**

```
function changeColor(curNumber){
    curNumber++;

    if(curNumber > 4){
        curNumber = 1;
    }
    document.body.setAttribute('class', 'color' + curNumber);
    setTimeout(function(){changeColor(curNumber)}, 2000);  
}

changeColor(0);
```

**Update animating color**

Second example requires Jquery UI if you wish to fade between classes or background colors.

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/7peJT/6/)**

```
function changeColor(element, curNumber){
    curNumber++;

    if(curNumber > 4){
        curNumber = 1;
    }

    element.addClass('color' + curNumber, 1000);

    // So previous classes get removed.
    element.attr('class', 'color' + curNumber);

    setTimeout(function(){changeColor(element, curNumber)}, 2000);  
}

changeColor($('#testElement'), 0);
```

Comment: hey, I actually came across this post while searching.  I need it to animate with JQuery so it fades each color in and out.

Comment: @RCNeil check out my update, you need to unclude jquery UI to add animations for adding class, or animating background colors.

Comment: yesssssssss this will work great!  Is there a way to repeat this function over and over?

Comment: That function above once kicked off will repeat forever, the timeout just keeps getting set at 2 seconds so it will never stop, or you can alternatively use setInterval(function(){},time) which will repeat forever without needed to reset the timeout.

Comment: ah nice.  yea it just wasn't doing it in the demo.  I placed it within a real site and it's working great!  Thank you so much.

Comment: only downside is there no animation effect between class 4 and 1 (green to black.)

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but just to show you a simple way of accomplishing this...

http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/QLPbW/5/

---

You want to use the [window.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval) function...

```
window.setInterval(rotateBG, 1000); // 1000 = 1 second

function rotateBG() {
    // logic to rotate background
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your tip!  What would I place as the "logic to rotate background?"