# Changing the backgound color of a div for a specified period of time then reverting in ASP .Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Using ASP .Net 4.0 I have an application where i was to flash the screen red or green, triggered from the code behind of the application. My thought on this was to have a Panel with a div inside of it like so

```
<asp:Panel ID="DisplayPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
        <div id="Display" style="height: 300px;"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

Then from the code behind make the panel show true, then somehow with javascript make it show red or green for say 2 seconds then have it revert and go back to the previous state, however i really don't know how to accomplish this, could someone assist me?

Comment: This should answer your question and more: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989584/change-background-color-css-with-timer-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will change the color of a div to green for 2 seconds

```
    function flashGreen(divID) {
        var element = document.getElementById(divID);
        var currentColor = element.style.backgroundColor;
        element.style.backgroundColor = '#0F0';
        setTimeout(function () {
            element.style.backgroundColor = currentColor
         }, 2000);
    }
```

You just need to call it when you want to trigger the event. For example, with a button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" OnClientClick="javascript: flashGreen('Display');return false;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following.  When the panel appears it will trigger the changeColor function mentioned in the earlier comment.

```
<asp:Panel ID="DisplayPanel" runat="server" Visible="false">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      changeColor('Display');
    });
    <div id="Display" style="height: 300px;"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: You might mention that this assumes jQuery

Comment: Yes, you are right.  I have used jQuery for so long it's like a reflex.