# Is there a way to change colours dynamically in CSS with a certain periodicity (i.e. every 30 seconds)?

Tags: css

This is my first post, so I apologize if this is inappropriate, but I was wondering if there's a way to ***make dynamic formatting in CSS***, changing styles at specific intervals in CSS3.

I found a previous discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18582555/change-color-with-css-over-time-back-and-forth), but when I tested the exact same code on VS, I didn't notice any dynamic changes as it was supposed to.

Here's the code for reference:

```
@-webkit-keyframes blackWhite {  
0% { background-color: white; }
50% { background-color: white; }
50% { background-color: black; }
100% { background-color: black; }
}

.blinkdiv {
height: 100px;
background-color: black;
\-webkit-animation-name: blackWhite;  
\-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;  
\-webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, are you talking about a fading background which is smooth instead of the sample which has no animation? or do you simply want to increase the animation-duration to 30s instead? Or is it about making the colors dynamic / switching them up? For me it is not really clear what you're trying to achieve, as the code shown, does exactly what you are talking about imo.

Comment: If I remove the `\ ` before your `-webkit-` styles, this works for me in a webkit browser (though you can probably discard the browser-specific rules, animation is widely supported now)

Comment: For me, in Firefox, your demo works [with](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/as8dyf1n/1/) or [without](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/as8dyf1n/) the back-slashes. Incidentally, you said you used the "*exact same code*," despite - for reasons unknown - changing the `51%` to `50%`. I don't know where, exactly, you're stuck but given the `animation-duration` of `2s`, the answer to your question is "*can you do this over a certain periodicity?*" is "yes." Also, what exactly do you mean by "*dynamically*"?

Comment: There's no question in this question...

Comment: @Dxg125 30s was just an example, I meant if the code is working for you and changing styles after the set time.

Comment: Hi @DavidThomas, you're absolutely right, I must have made a mistake while moving the code from the previous post to VS and back here again, my apologies. I can tell from other answers that there's probably something from on my end, I'll try to run the code again.

Comment: Thank you for checking, @DBS, as I said I'm still a novice so some things don't come naturally. If anyone has the power to close this answer, please feel free to do so, I can also delete it if it's considered clutter. Thank you all for taking the time to reply!