# Change Text Color in Sequence jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've had a look around and can't decide on the best way to go about doing this. I'm trying to animate the changing of a divs text colour in a sequence e.g. (#000, #eee, #fff...) every 1.5 seconds.

I know I need the jQuery Colour plugin as an addition to jQuery itself.

What would be the best way to go about this? Adding a CSS class to the div and rotating through them?

Any help would be brilliant!

**I need IE7 and IE8 compatibility**

Comment: How often do you want to do this? Is it just once going through a sequence, or perpetually? I was thinking maybe a CSS animation might be a good option too? (If that's available to you)

Comment: On average around every 1.5seconds it should change colour, just going through a sequence (1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5...). Looking for IE7-8 compatibility.

Comment: And how you define sequence? Start and end color, or you will set all colors?

Comment: What ways have you seen? Can you show what you currently have. Also, this is not a good idea in terms of accessibility/

Comment: It should appear as a colour for 1.5 seconds then switch to the next colour within the sequence.

Comment: If you're "adding a CSS class to the div and rotating" I think you can get away with not having to use the jQuery Color plugin.

Comment: @MisbahKhan Thanks, will this encounter performance issues?

Comment: Just cycle through an array with setTimout?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing as @Paulie_D, and keep track of the last one, so every time call removeClass(lastClass) and then addClass(currClass)

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989584/change-background-color-css-with-timer-jquery

Comment: @Jonathan, do you need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rtxr6s5e/2/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar to the [Jacob Gray answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31993508/361762) but I thought about something different when you said you wanted to *animate* the color changes. Here is one that uses CSS transitions to show the progressive color changes.

```js
var colorIndex = 0;
var colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "#aaa"];
var color = document.getElementById("color");
setInterval(function() {
    if (colorIndex >= colors.length)
        colorIndex = 0;
    color.style.backgroundColor = colors[colorIndex];
    colorIndex++;
}, 1500);
```

```css
#color {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    transition: background-color 1.5s;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="color"></div>
```

Comment: He want's IE7 support, and CSS transition is not supported in IE 7: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Comment: Ah, that wasn't noted in the question, but I do see the comment now. It will be a graceful degradation though--I feel bad for anyone who supports IE 7 in 2015.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I will be including your answer with a backup to none transition for IE7 below.

Comment: I think the answer is good enough. We should burn people who are still using IE 7 in 2016.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need jQuery, just do it like this:

```js
var colors = ["red","yellow","blue", "green", "purple"]; //Sets Colors
var target = document.getElementById("test"); //Target element
var currentColor = 0;
var time = 1500;//Time between color changes (in ms)
setInterval(function(){
    if( currentColor === colors.length) currentColor = 0;
    target.style.color = colors[currentColor];
    currentColor++;
},time);
```

```html
<div id="test">Change color NOW</div>
```

Comment: 500 should be 1500, since he wanted every 1.5 seconds

Comment: @RichardHamilton yeah, I forgot about that

Comment: Thanks Jacob! Brilliant answer, will be using a mix of yours and dave's answers!

Comment: @Jonathan glad I could help :D

Answer (score 0):

#### Warning: this answer uses CSS animations or transitions which require a decent browser, check availability :

animation : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

transition : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

You can try CSS animation too :

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}

.text {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  -webkit-animation: colorChange 5s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
  -moz-animation:    colorChange 5s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
  -o-animation:      colorChange 5s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
  animation:         colorChange 5s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
}

@keyframes colorChange {
  0% { color: hsl(0, 100%, 50%); }
  25% { color: hsl(90, 100%, 50%); }
  50% { color: hsl(180, 100%, 50%); }
  75% { color: hsl(270, 100%, 50%); }
  100% { color: hsl(360, 100%, 50%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="text">My Text</div>
```

You can go with CSS transitions and jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
  setInterval(function(){
    // execute every seconds
    $(".text").toggleClass("green");
  },1000);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #333;
}
.text {
  margin-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  transition: color 1s;
  color: #F00;
}

.text.green {
  color: #0F0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">My Text</div>
```

Comment: CSS3 transitions and animations aren't available until ie10.

Comment: sorry, what's ie ? :o)

Comment: @Apolo, most popular browser, even nowadays... :)

Comment: I'll add a warning in my answer. But OP may don't care about deprecated browsers

Comment: @Apolo he does "Looking for IE7-8 compatibility."

Comment: arf didn't read comments. I leave my answer for other people looking for solutions

Comment: and because I find the first one pretty, too :)