# how to change css after some seconds continously?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the stroke value black to white after some seconds continuously.

here is my script

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('svg').css({'stroke':'#000'});
})
</script>
```

Comment: You're changing the color to white, so once, why do you need to keep running this continuously?

Comment: because i want to add glow effect in it so i am trying it by changing white to black color continuously

Comment: I think that this answer will help you. He is changing the background color class. But it is the same concept. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989584/change-background-color-css-with-timer-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Try this](https://jsfiddle.net/harishkommuri/19tneg33/6/) similar one with css and jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   setInterval(function() {
   $("circle").attr("stroke", "white");
     setTimeout(function() {
       $("circle").attr("stroke", "black");
     }, 500);
   }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: yes it's working. Wait let me make it changing continously.

Answer (score 3):

I thought you meant

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function() { $('svg').toggleClass("white") },2000);
});
```

but you actually mean

```js
$(function(){
    var stroke = $('circle').attr("stroke");
    setInterval(function() { 
      stroke = stroke=="white"?"black":"white"
      $('circle').attr("stroke",stroke) 
    },2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>
```

Comment: Wait i will give you fiddle for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `recursive function` concept to achieve what you are trying to do

In the below code, you keep changing the status codes and colors will be changing accordingly. Here the function `changeColorFunc` calls itself every 2 seconds

Take a look at **JS FIDDLE** below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    changeColor(1);
}, 2000);
});


var changeColor = function changeColorFunc (status) {
    if (status == 1) {
       $("circle").attr("class", "white");
      setInterval(function() {
                    changeColorFunc (0);
      }, 2000);
    }
    if (status == 0) {
       $("circle").attr("class", "black");
      setInterval(function() {
                    changeColorFunc (1);
      }, 2000);
    }
}
```

**[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/pxjo77p1/2/)**